# The Boolean checkbox is working in reverse on VF page

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a search VF page where I show the list of records based on search. On select it will perform some action.

So the issue is when I select the checkbox it is returning False instead of true(checked in Debugs).

I am not able to find the cause for this. Can anyone please help me with this?

**Here is part of my code :**

```
public class searchpageclass {

public string searchstring{get; set;}
public List<cusobj__c> list123{get;set;}
String IdString;

List<cusobj__c> listCb; 
public String searchname{ get ; set;}


 public List<Wrapclass> cblist {get; set;}

    public PageReference PerformSearch() {

       if(searchname.length()==0){
          errorMessage = Label.Error;
         }



      listCb  =[select id,Name,Contact__c,Amount__c,Type__c from cusobj__c where type__c =: 'Code' and Name=:searchname];


       if(listCb.size()>1)
       {

       list123 = listCb;

       }

    public PageReference SelectedList() {

       if(searchname.length()==0){
          errorMessage = Label.Error1;
         }

    List<cusobj__c> selectedcb = new List<cusobj__c>();


    for(Wrapclass ac: getwrap()) {
    System.debug('Debug!!' +ac.select);// it is returning false when chekced on VF page
            if(ac.select == true) { 
                   selectedcb.add(ac.accidentifier);
                 }
        ac.select = false;
    }


    for(cusobj__c cbrec: selectedcb) {
                IdString = cbrec.id;
    }      

      listCb  =[select id,Name,Contact__c,Amount__c,Type__c from cusobj__c where Id=:IdString];

       if(listCb.size()>0)
       {
       //Will perform some action

          }
          else
          {
                return null;
   }

public List<Wrapclass> getwrap() {

       cblist.clear();

        for(cusobj__c p: list123) {
            cblist.add(new Wrapclass(p));

           }

    return cblist;
}

  public class Wrapclass {
    public cusobj__c cbrecs {get; set;}
    public Boolean select {get; set;}

    public Wrapclass (cusobj__c ai) {
        cbrecs = ai;
        select = false;
    }
  }

}
```

**Page :**

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!PerformSearch}" value="Search"  />

       <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!list.size > 1}" >
       <apex:pageBlock>
                  <br/><br/>

            <apex:pageblockTable value="{!wrap}" var="w" >
             <apex:column value="{!w.cbrecs.Name}"/>
             <apex:column value="{!w.cbrecs.Amount__c}"/>
             <apex:Column headerValue="Contact" >
             {!w.cbrecs.Contact__r.name}
             </apex:column>
            <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!w.select}" /> 

             <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" 
                                action="{!SelectedList }" />


             </apex:column>

         </apex:pageblockTable>


      </apex:pageBlock>
      </apex:outputPanel>
```

Comment: So the statement here     System.debug('Debug!!' +ac.selected); Is it a typo to use select instead of selected ?

Comment: @MohithShrivastava my bad in real code i added select. I corrected my code here

Comment: @MohithShrivastava Also If I add select=true in wrapper class and If I uncheck that in Vf page its working. So the thing is its working in reverse order.

Comment: Can you change event from onclick to onchange and see how it goes

Comment: Onchange is not working. I mean its not even calling the action

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46758/discussion-between-learner-and-mohith-shrivastava).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is the issue here

```
for(Wrapclass ac: getwrap()) {
```

Instead of using updated list you are filling the list with fresh set of data that why you are getting false in checkbox.
So update this for loop

```
for(Wrapclass ac: wrap) {
```

Also instead of getter method you should make a list variable and use that and rerender the table. Because if you rerender the table on ui you will lose all your change you made it on table.

You can use `cblist` in your for loop and on PBT this will give you correct result.

Comment: Thanks for your response. If I use  wrap instead of  getwrap,it is giving compile error "method doesn't exists"

Comment: @Learner I suggest you to use cblist in for loop and with PBT.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try, by changing the outputpanel code to

```
   <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!if(list.size > 1,true,false)}" >
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried your code but no change. Its again giving false when checked

Comment: You can always replace `IF(condition, true, false)` with simply `condition`...